# i have good pc can i mine on it, if i don't have to pay for electricity?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, gpu-mining

i have gtx 970 g1 gpu and intel i7 4790k cpu. i dont have to pay for my electricity costs. i used to play games but now i don't play them any-more. i was hopping someone will tell me if i can make a profit and how much i can make in a week by bitcion mining.
i dont have a clue how to mine if i will profit from mining can someone list in steps the things i need to start mining.

Main reason i got idea for mining is because i don't have to pay for electric costs. any advice will be helpfull

Comment: Google "bitcoin mining calculator". But note that even if it looks like you could mine one bitcoin in 1 000 to 10 000 years, in reality difficulty will go up during that time. You will probably be unable to ever reach the pool's minimum cash out amount, so you get nothing. Also there is the problem of staying alive for thousands of years.

Comment: These days a 1 TH/s ASIC machine is a small start for a mining-at-home operation.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. The days of GPU mining Bitcoins are long past.

Comment: can you suggest any other type of mining which only use gpu or cpu, i heard there are few of them, if you know them please tell me.

Comment: There really isn't any form of mining today that's likely to be profitable on hardware not chosen specifically for efficient mining. Your hardware is common, commodity hardware. Even if your electricity is free and you don't mind the heat, is the wear on your hardware worth the $1/month (being absurdly generous) you might get?

Comment: there are many froms out there whihc got information about minning using cpu and gpu like ziftr cion.

Comment: @danial, there is info about it, but it's from 3+ years ago when CPU/GPU mining was actually worth it. The world has moved on and doing it now is a waste of your time and useless wear and tear on your machine.